# Mongoose find between dates, order by ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I am trying to find all documents in a database between 'X' and 'X' dates and then order those by userID. This is what I have so far:

```
await Expense.find(
            {'date' :{'$gte': new Date(startDate), '$lte': new Date(endDate)}}),{sort: {_id: 1}}.exec(function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null));
                    expenseArray = data;
                    console.log(expenseArray);
```

But it keeps giving me "TypeError: {(intermediate value)}.exec is not a function"

For added clarification I am trying to write this in mongoose:

```
"SELECT employeeName, SUM(amount)
            FROM reimbursements
            WHERE d8 BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
            GROUP BY employeeName
            ORDER BY employeeName;";
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has few syntax issues, Please try this :

**Update :**

Below old code will work, but it would be better if you try this way :

```
try {
    let data = await Expense.find(
        { 'date': { '$gte': new Date(startDate), '$lte': new Date(endDate) } }).sort({ _id: 1 })

    /** .find() will not return null, it will either return [] or [with matched docs] */

    if (data.length) { // checks data != [] 
        console.log(data)
    } else { // data == []
        console.log('Empty - no docs found')
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error Fetching Model');
    console.log(error);
}
```

**Old :**

```
await Expense.find(
    { 'date': { '$gte': new Date(startDate), '$lte': new Date(endDate) } }).sort({ _id: 1 }).exec(function (err, data) { 
     /** sort is not an option for .find() not like aggregate, it has to be on cursor which is result of .find() & .exec() should be at end which is either .find() or .sort() */
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error Fetching Model');
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null));
        expenseArray = data;
        console.log(expenseArray)
    })
```

**Sample :** `mongooseModel.find().sort().exec()`

**Ref :** [cursor.sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/index.html)

Comment: Even if you pass `sort` as an option in `mongoose` it has to be like `mongooseModel.find({}, {} ,{sort : {}}).exec()`